# Beginner to Python Discord Music Bot

Tags: python

I'm just trying to get a discord bot to join a VC and play a song Pause & Stop but I am getting these errors.

*Edit: With me being new to Python I am not exactly sure how to fix this. I have read up about examples of these kinds of issues while trying to fix this and transferring them over to this problem has been uneventful with me just gaining more errors in the process.

**Old Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import music
  File "/home/runner/Adonnis/music.py", line 13, in <module>
    async def join(self,ctx):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1432, in decorator
    raise TypeError('Callback is already a command.')
TypeError: Callback is already a command.
```

**New Error**

```
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "join" is not found
```

**Main.py**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import music
print("Discord version ",discord.__version__)
print("Bot Running")

cogs = [music]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents = discord.Intents.all())

for i in range(len(cogs)):
  cogs[i].setup(client)

client.run(Token)
```

**Music.py**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
  def __innit__(self,client):
    self.client = client

# @commands.command()


@commands.command()
async def join(self,ctx):
  if ctx.author.voice is None:
    await ctx.send("You're not in a voice channel")
  voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
  if ctx.voice_client is None:
    await voice_channel.connect()
  else:
    await ctx.voice_channel.move_to(voice_channel)

@commands.command()
async def disconnect(self,ctx):
  await ctx.voice.client.disconnect()

@commands.command()
async def play(self,ctx,url):
  ctx.voice_client.stop()
  FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': 'vn'}
  YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': "bestaudio"}
  vc = ctx.voice_client

  with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
    info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
    url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
    source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
    vc.play(source)

@commands.command()
async def pause(self,ctx):
  await ctx.voice.client.pause()
  await ctx.send("Audio Paused ⏸")

@commands.command()
async def resume(self,ctx):
  await ctx.voice.client.resume()
  await ctx.send("Audio Resumed ⏯")

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(music(client))
```

I've coded this off of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHZlvRr9KxM

Is anyone able to assist me with the debugging of this?

*Edit: I have updated the "Error" sorry that was from an older version where I was trying what worked for someone else.

*Edit:

Packages used:

- Discord
- Discord.py
- Youtube_DL
- Pineapple

Just in case anyone wants to know what this was coded on also this was made on Replit.

Comment: Note that error message does not match your code. look at line 3 in main.py. According to traceback it is `from music.py import music`

Comment: Your error does not match with your code. The error says that the problem is `from music.py import music` at line 3 in your main but that line is `import music` in your code. Make sure you have the correct code and/or error message.

Comment: Also look at music.py. There are 2 decorators `@commands.command()` for `async def join(self,ctx):` I guess that's the cause for the error

Comment: I have edited the original error now sorry I must have gotten the older error by mistake. I don't know about decorators so will have to look them up :).  The Youtuber in the video showed it working with 2 decorators though which I find weird.

Comment: After looking back I found that it was what you said @buran. I have removed and am now getting my original error. "Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "join" is not found". Which was the issue I got stuck on initially again where it doesn't understand the command I send in Discord. ?join should join the Bot do the VC & play shouldn't work because the bot isn't in VC but it doesn't understand them at all. Any Ideas how to fix this error?